# OPENCSV double quotation mark inside the quote char will read as junk char --?

Tags: double-quotes, opencsv

This is my content for read:

> Systems Development Lifecycle (“SDLC”) process"
>   CSV read is: Systems Development Lifecycle (?SDLC?) process

How can I do correctly? The code what I tried is as follow:

```
public static List<Object> getUsingCSV(String fileName) throws IOException{ 

    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    CSVReader reader = null;

    try {

        FileInputStream fr = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fr,"UTF-8");

        reader = new CSVReader(isr,',','"', '|');
        String [] nextLine;

        while (((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null)) {
            list.add(nextLine);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally{
        reader.close();
    }

    return list;
}
```

But I am not lucky, that is not worked.

Comment: I am not sure why it is converting but have you tried escaping the quotes either with an extra quote or an escape character (in your case the | character.  This tells opencsv you want to keep the quote.

Answer (score 1):

Because those two quotation marks are not part of `ANSI` or `ASCII`. If you are using Windows then you might try using `System.console().writer().println()` instead of `System.out.println()`.

Answer (score 0):

What is your default character set - that may be the issue. I tried recreating the failure but could not. Unfortunately I don't have enough space to put my test in but one of the things I added was the following print. System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset().displayName()); If your display character set is different than the input character set that could explain the question marks